# how to put a datagrid column values to the innertexts of an xml in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a datagrid showing two columns,ID and Description. and have created an xml like..

```
<Material ID="Steel">
  <Property ID="Shape" name="Shape">Description</Property>
  <Property ID="Weight" name="Weight">Description</Property>
  .........
</Material>
```

now how can I put the Description column values in the innertext of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could try:

```
DataSet.WriteXml(stringpath/filestream + filename.xml)
```

It's the least painful way of doing it IMO